# How can I install pyautogui on a Debian environnement on a Python2.7?

Tags: python, linux, pip, debian, pyautogui

I am trying install this pyautogui, unsuccesfully.

I tried: `pip install pyautogui`

Result: it started to installing, pillow in local, collecting zip file, etc, and suddenly stop and write this error message:

> "File /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/HERE CHANGE A FEW TEXT LIKE
>   pip, PyTweenig,etc.. and after these OS ERROR: [ERRNO13] permission
>   denied
>   'usr/local/lib/Python2.7/dist-packages/PyTweening-1.0.2.dist_info'

If I am trying with : `sudo pip install pyautogui`

Result:

> Xlib.Error.DisplayConnectionError:Can't connect to display:"1" No
>   protocol specified. Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with
>   error code 1 in tmp/pip-build-2t6aey/pyautogui

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved with this :

```
sudo chmod 777 'usr/local/lib/Python2.7/dist-packages'
```